# AndEngine Third time I setText it crashes

Tags: java, text, crash, andengine, settext

ATM I'm making a game in AndEngine for a school project. Nevertheless I've setup a entity with a loopModifier with a MoveModifier and when the movemodifier is complete the score will +10 and the text will update by

> scoreText.setText("Score: " + Score);

This actually works totally fine and the text updates until the third time when the game crash.

Some code to analyze.

```
private void spawnEnemy(Scene scene){
    Lane = r.nextInt(6)+1;
    enemy = new Sprite(-300, 0, playerTR, this.activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    moveModifier = new MoveModifier(speed, -GameManager.lengthOfTile * 2, camera.getWidth() + GameManager.lengthOfTile*2, Lane * GameManager.lengthOfTile, Lane * GameManager.lengthOfTile){
        @Override
        protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
            super.onModifierFinished(pItem);
            Lane = r.nextInt(6)+1;
            Score += 10;
            Log.i("Score: ", "" + Score);
            textScore.setText("Score: " + Score);
            Log.i("setText", "COMPLETE");
        }
    };
    enemy.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(moveModifier));
    scene.attachChild(enemy);
}

private void initHUD(Scene scene) {
    input.loadInput(scene);
    hud = new hud(activity, hearthTR, camera.getWidth(), camera.getHeight());
    textScore = new Text(10, 0, font, "Score: " + Score, "Score: 1234567890".length() +1, this.activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    hud.attachChild(textScore);
    camera.setHUD(hud);
}
```

**Logcat**

```
01-17 11:03:41.029: I/Score:(15748): 10
01-17 11:03:41.049: I/setText(15748): COMPLETE
01-17 11:03:41.089: D/dalvikvm(15748): GC_EXPLICIT freed 34K, 10% free 9267K/10275K, paused 2ms+4ms
01-17 11:03:41.930: D/dalvikvm(2174): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1201K, 33% free 18034K/26851K, paused 43ms
01-17 11:03:42.050: D/dalvikvm(2174): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 18K, 26% free 19930K/26851K, paused 34ms
01-17 11:03:42.050: I/dalvikvm-heap(2174): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.785MB for 4410016-byte allocation
01-17 11:03:42.100: D/dalvikvm(2174): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 24237K/26851K, paused 35ms
01-17 11:03:42.191: D/dalvikvm(2174): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 10% free 24237K/26851K, paused 2ms+15ms
01-17 11:03:43.982: I/Score:(15748): 20
01-17 11:03:43.982: I/setText(15748): COMPLETE
01-17 11:03:44.022: D/dalvikvm(15748): GC_EXPLICIT freed 52K, 10% free 9266K/10275K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-17 11:03:46.975: I/Score:(15748): 30
01-17 11:03:48.907: I/ActivityManager(1812): Start proc com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.uxpnxt for service com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.uxpnxt/com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.publisher.calendar.NewReminderService: pid=15798 uid=10029 gids={3003}
01-17 11:03:49.067: I/ActivityThread(15798): Pub com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.provider: com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.event.LockScreenEventProvider
01-17 11:03:59.648: I/touchd(1453): 'ab8500_usb' is online
01-17 11:03:59.648: I/touchd(1453): handling_uevent: event is 1
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400): Exception during service
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com": No address associated with hostname
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(FbHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:101)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:176)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:158)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpClientRequestExecutor.a(FbHttpClientRequestExecutor.java:45)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.executors.QeHttpRequestExecutor.a(QeHttpRequestExecutor.java:50)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.RequestFlowStateController.a(RequestFlowStateController.java:67)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbRedirectController.a(FbRedirectController.java:92)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:160)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:139)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:103)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:196)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:374)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:151)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:26)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiMethodRunnerImpl.a(ApiMethodRunnerImpl.java:43)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiMethodRunnerImpl.a(ApiMethodRunnerImpl.java:35)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.orca.protocol.WebServiceHandler.b(WebServiceHandler.java:302)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:31)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.orca.database.DbServiceHandler.b(DbServiceHandler.java:256)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:31)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.handlers.RemoteStubHandler.a(RemoteStubHandler.java:32)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.handlers.RemoteProxyHandler.a(RemoteProxyHandler.java:60)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.orca.cache.CacheServiceHandler.b(CacheServiceHandler.java:138)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:31)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:299)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:53)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:230)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
01-17 11:04:09.437: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(2400):  at libcore.io.Pos
```

Comment: Can you provide logcat error information? p.s. sorry that i can't add comment because lack of reputation.

Comment: I've have added logcat information now.

Comment: I think your logcat didn't involve your 'Text' at all.
 Did you capture this log when your app was crashed?

Comment: Yes, look from 11:03:41.029 to 11:03:59.648

Comment: if look only the logcat i don't think the problem wasn't your text at all. but it was caused by can't connect to "graph.facebook.com".
Did you use anything related to "graph.facebook.com"?

Comment: The phone I use to debug my application on has Facebook running in the background but I don't use any feacebook feature in my application. Would be odd if that was the problem, will check removing it though.